# How to set max height to the div after expanding the content?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have added equal height to the divs. I need to set the same height of all the div after expanding the content.

But after I expand those divs, for the height text and BG cut off. Could I add the height of the bigger element dynamically? if yes, then How?

Please see the below code to understand better.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clicktoexpand').click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle');
    $(this).parent('.choosebot').find('.areaexpand').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.whychooseus {
  padding: 80px 0 0;
}

.choosetop {
  text-align: left;
}

.choosetop .icon {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.choosetop .ic-txt {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.choosetop .ic-txt h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.choosetop.iconholder-1 {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}

.choosetop.iconholder-1:hover {
  background-color: #104a9b;
}

.choosetop.iconholder-1:hover:after {
  background: url(../images/pat.png) repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.choosebot {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.choosebot p {
  color: #7f7f7f;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.choosebot:after {
  background: url(../images/pat.png) repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.areaexpand {
  display: none;
}

.choosebot p,
.choosebot a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.choosebot a.clicktoexpand {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #00cde7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="whychooseus">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="choosebot">
          <p> For our customers,this is key. When we say we will deliver <span class="areaexpand">
          something,we mean it. <br><br>We have tried and tested,industry leading in-house processes that ensure you get nothing but the best in customer service from us. <br><br>Our services are backed up with SLAs and guarantees, and most importantly,we understand our accountability. </span></p>
          <a class="clicktoexpand" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="choosebot">
          <p> Communication: It's not just what we do, it's how we <span class="areaexpand">operate. <br><br>We keep you informed at all times,and our technical support teams a responsive and personable. Most Importantly, you can trusl lhat they havo tho knowledge to resolve any issues quickly Our oxportise puts us in the ideal position to be your single point of contact for all your voice and data needs.</span></p>
          <a class="clicktoexpand" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="choosebot">
          <p>Our in-house engineers and support staff are all Industry <span class="areaexpand">accredited and qualified. <br><br>Our Account Managers also know their stuff, meaning we continue to support you fully after your solution has bean delivered. making rocommondations for improvements and keeping you aware of new technologies that might help your business succeed rurther. </span></p>
          <a class="clicktoexpand" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="choosebot">
          <p>We don't Just mean commercially, although we will<span class="areaexpand">always strive to deliver solutions that are cost effective. <br><br>We also mean the value we bring to your business communications solution:our trustworthiness.our considerable knowledge and our reliability at all times.</span> </p>
          <a class="clicktoexpand" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any reason, why you are using Bootstrap version 3 and not version 4?

Comment: Client has some purposes for using bootstrap 3.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to switch? Bootstrap 4 is so superior to all the previous version, because it utilizes `display: flex` for columns, which makes same height a piece of cake

Answer (score 0):

I only have a solution for Bootstrap Version 4 here.
It toggle's all the expandable areas simultaiously.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clicktoexpand').click(function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('.row')
        .find('.areaexpand')
          .slideToggle()
        .end()
        .find('.clicktoexpand')
          .find('i')
           .toggleClass('fa-minus-circle')
           .toggleClass('fa-plus-circle');
  });
});
```

```css
.whychooseus {
  padding: 80px 0 0;
}

.choosetop {
  text-align: left;
}

.choosetop .icon {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.choosetop .ic-txt {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.choosetop .ic-txt h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.choosetop.iconholder-1 {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}

.choosetop.iconholder-1:hover {
  background-color: #104a9b;
}

.choosetop.iconholder-1:hover:after {
  background: url(../images/pat.png) repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.choosebot {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.choosebot p {
  color: #7f7f7f;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.choosebot:after {
  background: url(../images/pat.png) repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.areaexpand {
  display: none;
}

.choosebot p,
.choosebot a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.choosebot a.clicktoexpand {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #00cde7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="whychooseus">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
        <div class="choosebot">
          <p> For our customers,this is key. When we say we will deliver <span class="areaexpand">
          something,we mean it. <br><br>We have tried and tested,industry leading in-house processes that ensure you get nothing but the best in customer service from us. <br><br>Our services are backed up with SLAs and guarantees, and most importantly,we understand our accountability. </span></p>
          <a class="clicktoexpand" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
        <div class="choosebot">
          <p> Communication: It's not just what we do, it's how we <span class="areaexpand">operate. <br><br>We keep you informed at all times,and our technical support teams a responsive and personable. Most Importantly, you can trusl lhat they havo tho knowledge to resolve any issues quickly Our oxportise puts us in the ideal position to be your single point of contact for all your voice and data needs.</span></p>
          <a class="clicktoexpand" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
        <div class="choosebot">
          <p>Our in-house engineers and support staff are all Industry <span class="areaexpand">accredited and qualified. <br><br>Our Account Managers also know their stuff, meaning we continue to support you fully after your solution has bean delivered. making rocommondations for improvements and keeping you aware of new technologies that might help your business succeed rurther. </span></p>
          <a class="clicktoexpand" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
        <div class="choosebot">
          <p>We don't Just mean commercially, although we will<span class="areaexpand">always strive to deliver solutions that are cost effective. <br><br>We also mean the value we bring to your business communications solution:our trustworthiness.our considerable knowledge and our reliability at all times.</span>            </p>
          <a class="clicktoexpand" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if I can use bootstrap 4 then it would be a piece of cake... but I cant switch you know. and i done want to expand all at same time. Thanks for your code, Great for BS4.